# How do i properly test Laravel events?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, mockery

I'm writing tests for a model which fires an event when one of its properties is changed. Unfortunately, I can't figure out the best way to test this. The model code is:

```
class Foo extends Eloquent {
   public function setNameAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['name'] = $value;
        if($this->exists && ($this->original['name'] != $value)) {
            Event::fire('foo.NameChange', array($this));
        }
    }
}
```

My initial test for the event fire:

```
$bar = Foo::first();
Event::shouldReceive('fire')->once()->with('foo.NameChange', array($bar));
$bar->name = 'test';
```

The problem is, the above tests still pass if:

- no event occurred at all
- I'm changing the model's name for a second time (which, should fire
  the event for a second time, right?)

How can i make my tests pass only if one `foo.NameChange` event occurred? All other senario's should fail my test.

Comment: Your test should fail if no `event` occured at all - as you've mocked it and said it should be fired `once`?

Comment: Did you call `Mockery::close()`?, also see my explanation on an [old SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035549/mockery-shouldreceive-once-doesnt-seem-to-work/16308814#16308814)

Comment: Thanks a lot @BramGerritsen! closing the test with an `Mockery::close()` statement did fix it! Could you be so kind to convert your comment to an answer? Also i wonder why this is not mentioned in the official documentation of [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing#mocking-facades).

Comment: I don't use Laravel myself, but I think it should definitely be mentioned in the manual. Maybe you could notify the framework authors about it. Nothing is so frustrating when learning a framework when you have to deal with non working example code in official tutorials.

Comment: @nstapelbroek Do mind that you don't *have* to call `Mockery::close()` in each test, *if* you set it up for the entire suite (see the manual referenced by Bram).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `Mockery::close()` in your `tearDown()` method.
See the [Mockery docs](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/phpunit_integration.html?highlight=close) on PHPUnit integration.